How can I add HTTP cache headers in SolidJS/Solid Start?
How can I add Cache-Control headers to static files and route responses in Solid Start?

Since Solid Start uses Nitro you can just add this to your app.config.ts file:
import { defineConfig } from "@solidjs/start/config";

const aYear = 31536000;
export default defineConfig({
  server: {
    // ...
    routeRules: {
      "/images/**": {
        headers: {
          "cache-control": `public,max-age=${aYear},s-maxage=${aYear}`,
        },
      },
    },
  },
});

